# Convert glib C method with string array as parameter to Go

Tags: c, go, glib

I am trying to add some methods to the [gotk3/glib](https://github.com/gotk3/gotk3/tree/master/glib) Go repository, but I am having troubles converting the method [`g_settings_set_strv`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GSettings.html#g-settings-set-strv) to Go; the C signature is this:

```
gboolean
g_settings_set_strv (GSettings *settings,
                     const gchar *key,
                     const gchar *const *value);
```

And this is what I have in Go (adapted copy paste, I am not a C guy, only Java, Python, etc.):

```
// SetStrv is a wrapper around g_settings_set_strv().
func (v *Settings) SetStrv(name string, values []string) bool {
    cstr1 := (*C.gchar)(C.CString(name))
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cstr1))

    cvalues := C.make_strings(C.int(len(values) + 1))
    defer C.destroy_strings(cvalues)

    for i, accel := range values {
        cstr := C.CString(accel)
        defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cstr))
        C.set_string(cvalues, C.int(i), (*C.gchar)(cstr))
    }
    C.set_string(cvalues, C.int(len(values)), nil)
    return gobool(C.g_settings_set_strv(v.native(), cstr1, cvalues))
}
```

But build fails with this message:

```
./settings.go:246: cannot use (*C.gchar)(cstr) (type *C.gchar) as type *C.char in argument to func literal
./settings.go:249: cannot use cvalues (type **C.char) as type **C.gchar in argument to func literal
```

I am stuck in this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works and does what is supposed to:

```
// SetStrv is a wrapper around g_settings_set_strv().
func (v *Settings) SetStrv(name string, values []string) bool {
    cstr1 := (*C.gchar)(C.CString(name))
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cstr1))

    // cvalues := C.make_strings(C.int(len(values) + 1))
    cvalues := make([]*C.gchar, len(values))

    for i, accel := range values {
        cvalues[i] = (*C.gchar)(C.CString(accel))
        defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cvalues[i]))
    }
    cvalues = append(cvalues, nil)

    // C.set_string(cvalues, C.int(len(values)), nil)
    return gobool(C.g_settings_set_strv(v.native(), cstr1, &cvalues[0]))
}
```

Thanks to [tommyshem from github](https://github.com/tommyshem) for his help ([commit fix](https://github.com/gotk3/gotk3/pull/225#issuecomment-353794102)).